# Don't want to hold 3 seconds to invoked didSelectRowAtIndexPath after playing streaming

Tags: uitableview, swift

I created a iOS app in `swift` with custom cell and a `VLCPlayer`. In my project, I will click a specific cell and the `VLCPlayer` will download the video according to the `fileID` in that cell.

When the `VLCPlayer` is not show any streaming, the `UITableView` works fine, and the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` invoked immediately.

My Problem is:
After my `VLCPlayer` become to play the streaming, I have to hold 3 seconds in that cell to invoke `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, but I want it to invoke immediately.

Can anyone tell me how to deal with this problem?

Here is my code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TimelineTableViewCell

    let motionImage:UIImage!
    motionImage = UIImage (named: "motion.png")


    if self.items[indexPath.row].image == nil
    {
        cell.snapshotImage.image = UIImage(named: "loading_page.png")
    }
    else
    {
        cell.snapshotImage.image = self.items[indexPath.row].image
    }
    cell.motionImage.image = motionImage
    cell.dayLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.row].text
    cell.timeLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.row].date

    //update the cell image
    if self.items[indexPath.row].image == nil
    {            
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)){

            //1. trying to get the image from cache
            var image: AnyObject? = timelineImageCache.objectForKey(userDefaults.stringForKey("cameraName")! + self.items[indexPath.row].fileID! + fileIdentifer)

            //2. trying to get the image from filesystem
            let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String
            let folderPath = path.stringByAppendingPathComponent("timelineImage/")
            let destinationPath = folderPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent(userDefaults.stringForKey("cameraName")! + self.items[indexPath.row].fileID! + fileIdentifer + ".jpg")
            var fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
            if image == nil
            {
                if (fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(destinationPath))
                {
                    image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: destinationPath)
                    println("File System")
                }

            }

            //3. if there's no cache and not exist in file system, then download it
            if image == nil
            {
                image = WebstorageConnection.getVideoSnapshot(self.items[indexPath.row].fileID!)
                //imageCache[timeframe.fileID!] = image
                timelineImageCache.setObject(image!, forKey: userDefaults.stringForKey("cameraName")! + self.items[indexPath.row].fileID! + fileIdentifer)
                FileSystemManager.instance.saveImageToLoacl(image as! UIImage, fileName: userDefaults.stringForKey("cameraName")! + self.items[indexPath.row].fileID! + fileIdentifer)
                println("Done Download")
            }


            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){

                cell.snapshotImage.image = image as? UIImage
                //println("UI")
            }


        }


    }

    return cell

}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    println("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")

    let url = WebstorageConnection.getDirectDownloadURL(fileID: items[indexPath.row].fileID!)
    vlcPlayer.stop()
    vlcLoadingIndicator.startAnimating()
    let media : VLCMedia = VLCMedia(URL: url) as VLCMedia
    vlcPlayer.media = media
    vlcPlayer.play()    

}
```

Thanks for everyone!

Comment: I found the problem is the VLCPlayer, when I stop it's streaming, my 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath' works fine. But I don't know how to stop the streaming when user want to click some cell.

Comment: After I try many times, I found that maybe a view can't do so much things in the same time. Therefore, my tableView will react very slow.
Does anyone have the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

You want to disabled `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` for 3 sec. after playing. Correct?

```
var isAllowed = Bool() // default is true

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    println("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")

    let url = WebstorageConnection.getDirectDownloadURL(fileID: items[indexPath.row].fileID!)
    vlcPlayer.stop()
    vlcLoadingIndicator.startAnimating()
    let media : VLCMedia = VLCMedia(URL: url) as VLCMedia
    vlcPlayer.media = media
    vlcPlayer.play()

    isAllowed = false
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)){
        NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(3) // sleeps for 3 sec.
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
            isAllowed = true
        }
    }
}
```

or use timer

```
var isAllowed = Bool() // default is true

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    println("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")

    let url = WebstorageConnection.getDirectDownloadURL(fileID: items[indexPath.row].fileID!)
    vlcPlayer.stop()
    vlcLoadingIndicator.startAnimating()
    let media : VLCMedia = VLCMedia(URL: url) as VLCMedia
    vlcPlayer.media = media
    vlcPlayer.play()
    isAllowed = false

    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3, target: self, selector: Selector("yourSelector"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}

func yourSelector() {
    isAllowed = true
}
```

this will do the magic and will not allow the user from selecting the cell at indexPath... under

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? 
{
    //return nil if you dont want to allow selection
    if (isAllowed == false)
    {
       return nil
    }
    return indexPath
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have try this but it still don't work for me. And why should it sleep for 3 seconds? thanks

Comment: There.. Done.. You can try it now. :)

Comment: hi, I've try this, but now it can't play the streaming, I think the problem is in the 'willSelectRowAtIndexPath' method.
Should I add else statement in 'willSelectRowAtIndexPath' that will return indexPath?
Thanks for reply!!

Comment: yes.. `return indexPath` and `isAllowed = true` by default

Comment: Hi, I think there's a misunderstood, sorry for my bad expression.
Actually, the situation that "I have to hold 3 seconds in that cell to invoke 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath'." did annoy me.
So I want it to be invoked immediately even the streaming is playing. But now it can't do this.